# Multiple div printing

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

How can I print several div with the same id because 
I'm looping the div and it retains the `id=PrintArea` all the time.

I'm using PrintArea for printing my div.

and with this JS:

```
function printDiv() {
           var divToPrint = document.getElementById('printArea');
           newWin= window.open();
           newWin.document.write(divToPrint.innerHTML);
           newWin.location.reload();
           newWin.focus();
           newWin.print();
           newWin.close();
       }
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. No HTML document should contain the same id for an element twice. Element/div ids are meant to be unique in a document. Are you talking about overwriting/replacing a div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a class name for the divs to print, then the loop:

```
var divsToPrint = document.getElementsByClassName('printArea'), n;

for (n = 0; n < divsToPrint.length; n++) {
    printDiv(divsToPrint[n]);
}

function printDiv(div) {
    var newWin= window.open('', 'win');
    newWin.document.write(div.innerHTML);
    newWin.location.reload();
    newWin.focus();
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
}
```

Also please visit at MDN to see, how [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) is called.

However, it would be much simpler, if you'd use a stylesheet with `media="print"` attribute. In this stylesheet there should be three classes: `.noprint {display: none;}` for all the content not to be printed, `.printable {display: none;}` for those divs to be printed, and `.print {display: block;}`, which is toggled with `.printable`, when actually printing.

Answer (score 1):

To print multiple div content together

```
function printMultipleDiv()
{
    var divsToPrint = document.getElementsByClassName('printArea');
    var printContents = "";
    for (n = 0; n < divsToPrint.length; n++) 
    {
       printContents += divsToPrint[n].innerHTML+"<br>";
    }
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```